# Tortoise SVN Commit uncheck by default

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, multipleselection

I was wondering if there is a way to set the checkbox default setting to not checked/none when you try to commit files into the repository. The default setting for commit is set to check all, but I would like to avoid running into the scenario where I accidentally check in items by mistake. Is there a way to configure the setup for SVN to uncheck the boxes when you first hit the commit button?

Comment: Meanwhile (TortoiseSVN 1.9.6) there is a maybe [more general solution available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45998001/2932052)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simple, you have the option here

> Menu Settings -> Dialog 2 -> Select Items Automatically = uncheck

[image]

Comment: maybe interesting for you that there is [selection-(un)checking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45998001/2932052) implemented meanwhile.

Comment: @Wolf good to know, mainly switched to git now but it is useful nevertheless

Answer (score 4):

A really cool feature I found today that is also a solution for the problem described. It's possible to check or un-check multiple items at once.

If you select items in the list (maybe all by pressing `Alt`+`A`), you can change the check on the selection. Just click on one item contained within the selection.

## before

[image]

## after

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can uncheck specific files by default using a special changelist named `ignore-on-commit`.

- In the Commit dialog, perform (on a file with changes) `Right click > Move to changelist`.
- Name the changelist `ignore-on-commit`

The next time you open the Commit dialog, the file will be unselected.

This works also in IntelliJ etc.